# MVC Area and controller with the same name

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, routes, asp.net-mvc-3-areas

I am working on MVC3 application. My folder structure for the application is:

```
Areas
    Admin
        Controller
            AdminController
```

The AdminController has an EditUser method. To go to this method, I have to use the following URL:

```
http://localhost/Admin/Admin/EditUser
```

I like the folder structure of the application, but I want to get away with typing Admin twice in the URL. I want the URL to look like:

```
http://localhost/Admin/EditUser
```

How would I be able to do this? I am looking into routing, but need more clarification regarding this. Any help would be appreciated.

UPDATE:
Ok, so I have added the following to the Routing information under Global.asax.cs file.

```
routes.MapRoute("Admin",
    "Admin/Admin/{action}/{id}",
    new { action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
```

This takes me to the correct controller method, but the view cannot be found when i use the following statement:

```
return View();
```

Do I need to add something in the area registration as well for this to work?

Comment: This question can be usefull for you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3337372/asp-net-mvc-removing-controller-name-from-url

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7341075/asp-net-mvc-3-controller-route-make-everything-under-home-controller-appear-un

Comment: here is the question that helped me in solving my issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6763039/mvc-3-does-not-look-for-views-under-areas